# Random routing errors in Rails public routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a jQuery Mobile website to be turned into a PhoneGap/Cordova app. To facilitate this, I created a brand new rails project, and after changing to the 'thin' gem for a webserver, put the entire jQuery Mobile app in the public/myapp folder of the new Rails project.

This all works fine; I can reach my mobile app from localhost:3000/myapp but after a few hours of testing suddenly the Rails app starts throwing 404s all over the place. What is likely to have happened?

This is ONE of the errors I see in the rails server logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/js/setlocation_address.js"
```

Basically every single reference in my `<head>` tag to a javascript or css file returns with a 404 error.

Comment: If this is a Rails 3 project you might need to check that the asset pipeline isn't causing trouble. I'm not sure how long JavaScript files stick around in development mode when the HTML referencing them isn't triggered.

Comment: It is rails 3, but I thought the asset pipeline doesn't effect the public folder?

Comment: Oh, if you're putting them in the public folder you're probably just making the asset pipeline angry. As far as I know, that method is deprecated unless you've completely disabled the asset pipeline feature. Is your server software okay with serving other static files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution was to put

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in the `config/environments/production.rb` file but I'm not sure if this solved the issue as it was an intermittent one.

EDIT

Actually it seems the problem was that I would sometimes go to `localhost:3000/myapp` and sometimes to `localhost:3000/myapp/index.html` .

Although Rails would route me to the same index.html page each time, my browser wouldn't pickup the relative paths correctly, and would try to GET `localhost:3000/css/styles.css` instead of `localhost:3000/myapp/css/styles.css`.